# SQL Server: determining the Years, Months, Weeks and Days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

After reading on this topic and being advised to use `DateDiff`. I wrote a function that doesn't provide the answer I want. The client wants to now how long it took to complete a checklist. I have a `CreationDate` and `CompletionDate`. I need to know how many years, months, weeks and days it took. If it is 2 days then '2 days' without the years. The function deducts the number of years and then attempt to check the number of months, then the number of weeks and then the number of days. Only results are given if available. It seems `DateDiff` is the problem... or I am the problem not understanding `DateDiff`. It even returns a week for a 4 day difference in dates which doesn't make sense. It should return the number of weeks within the two dates, not caring when it starts.

This is the code

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRangeText]
    (@FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Result = '';

    DECLARE @TmpS AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @TmpS = '';

    DECLARE @Years AS INT;
    SET @Years = DATEDIFF(year, @FromDate, @ToDate);
    IF (@Years > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@Years = 1)
            SET @TmpS = ' Year ';
        ELSE
            SET @TmpS = ' Years ';

        SET @Result = @Result + CAST(@Years AS VARCHAR) + @TmpS;
        SET @ToDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1 * @Years, @ToDate);
    END;

    DECLARE @Months AS INT;
    SET @Months = DATEDIFF(month, @FromDate, @ToDate);
    IF (@Months > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@Months = 1)
            SET @TmpS = ' Month ';
        ELSE
            SET @TmpS = ' Months ';

        SET @Result = @Result + CAST(@Months AS VARCHAR) + @TmpS;
        SET @ToDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -1 * @Months, @ToDate);
    END;

    DECLARE @Weeks AS INT;
    SET @Weeks = DATEDIFF(week, @FromDate, @ToDate);
    IF (@Weeks > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@Weeks = 1)
            SET @TmpS = ' Week ';
        ELSE
            SET @TmpS = ' Weeks ';

        SET @Result = @Result + CAST(@Weeks AS VARCHAR) + @TmpS;
        SET @ToDate = DATEADD(WEEK, -1 * @Weeks, @ToDate);
    END;

    DECLARE @Days AS INT;
    SET @Days = DATEDIFF(day, @FromDate, @ToDate);
    IF (@Days > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@Days = 1)
            SET @TmpS = ' Day ';
        ELSE
            SET @TmpS = ' Days ';

        SET @Result = @Result + CAST(@Days AS VARCHAR) + @TmpS;
        SET @ToDate = DATEADD(WEEK, -1 * @Days, @ToDate);
    END;

    IF (@Result = '')
        SET @Result = 'Same day';

    RETURN Rtrim(COALESCE(@Result,''));
END;
```

Comment: "*After reading on this topic*". What topic? What is your question here?

Comment: DATEDIFF counts the number of thresholds crossed between two dates. It is not really what you are looking for here. What isn't clear to me though is what you are really trying to do.

Comment: And now i know why this looks familiar: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1932589/Determining-the-Years-Months-Weeks-and-Days-between-two-dates

Comment: You say it isn't returning what you want, what do you want it to return. For two dates say '20170101 10:34:000' and '20180418 13:34:000' what should be returned?

Comment: Well yes, I posted the question there as well. All I want to do is to determine how long someone took to complete a checklist e.g. 1 day or 1 year, 2 months, 3 weeks, 4 days etc etc.

Comment: You did post there as well, yes, but people have responded to you there, and you hadn't replied to them when you posted this question. Rather than posting the same question on a different help website, you should be answering their questions. The statements and questions you'll get here will be the same, so your net gain is answering the questions on your original topic; not creating a brand new question.

Comment: For two dates say '20170101 10:34:000' and '20180418 13:34:000' I want the following to be returned: 1 Year, 3 months, 2 weeks, 3 days

Comment: what about leap years...

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using a function, consider the following Table-Valued Function.  Easy to use a stand-alone or included as a CROSS APPLY.

Performant and Accurate without having to worry about all the misc date calculations.

**Example**

```
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
```

**Returns**

```
Years   Months  Days    Hours   Minutes Seconds
26      7       5       13      47      11
```

**The TVF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          --,[Elapsed] = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')
```

Comment: Does this account for leap years? Just curious.

Comment: @scsimon yup - give me a moment and I'll post a dbfiddle

Comment: @scsimon just not weeks as OP mentioned

Comment: Awe come on... you could get weeks in there somehow couldn't you! HAHA. But i wonder what they consider a week, because SQL Server considers it any change in the week, not 7 consecutive days.

Comment: @scsimon Exactly, thus the reason for excluding weeks.  So I keep it to a defensible answer  :)

Comment: @scsimon  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c7cd09dc467dc2a2836ae3e53de591f7

Comment: Much appreciated. Client changed his requirements now to days, hours and minutes, but that is easier. Agree that it is better to keep weeks out.Thank you for your assistance and kindness.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave weeks and leap years to you to figure out unless I have time to come back to this later. However this will get you the years, months, and days you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DateTime
DECLARE @ToDate DateTime
DECLARE @years INT
DECLARE @months INT
DECLARE @days INT

-- just some sample dates for testing   
Set @FromDate = '01-01-2014'
Set @ToDate = GetDate()

SET @years = DATEDIFF(mm, @FromDate, @ToDate)/12
SET @months = DATEDIFF(mm, @FromDate, @ToDate)%12 - 1
SET @days = ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm,@months , DATEADD(yy, @years, @FromDate)), @ToDate))

DECLARE @YearsStr VarChar(20)
DECLARE @MonthsStr VarChar(20)
DECLARE @DaysStr VarChar(20)

SET @YearsStr = Case When @years > 0 Then Convert(varchar(10),@years) + ' Years, ' Else '' End
SET @MonthsStr = Case When @months > 0 Then Convert(varchar(10),@months) + ' Months, ' Else '' End
SET @DaysStr = Convert(varchar(10),@days) + ' Days '

SELECT @YearsStr + @MonthsStr + @DaysStr
```