# Is there any way to get period from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns i need to get the different period with days and hours
Example

```
2019-10-22 13:22:59 min getdate()
```

I need result to be

```
3 days 7 hours
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates to find time difference in SQL Server 2005, date manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521434/how-to-compare-two-dates-to-find-time-difference-in-sql-server-2005-date-manipu)

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903501/sql-server-determining-the-years-months-weeks-and-days-between-two-dates/49903984#49903984